# Ruby FileUtils.move Errno::EACCES: Permission denied on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows

How do you move files on Windows with Ruby? Looking at the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-i-mv) it appears as though it should work with `FileUtils.move`. This is not working for me on Windows 10.

```
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.3.0"
irb(main):002:0> require 'fileutils'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> FileUtils.mkdir("first_directory")
=> ["first_directory"]
irb(main):004:0> FileUtils.mkdir("second_directory")
=> ["second_directory"]
irb(main):005:0> FileUtils.touch(File.join("first_directory", "test_file"))
=> ["first_directory/test_file"]
irb(main):006:0> file = File.new(File.join("first_directory", "test_file"))
=> #<File:first_directory/test_file>
irb(main):007:0> FileUtils.move(file, "second_directory")
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename - (first_directory/test_file, second_directory/test_file)
        from C:/ruby/23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:528:in `rename'
        from C:/ruby/23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:528:in `block in mv'
        from C:/ruby/23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1571:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
        from C:/ruby/23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1585:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
        from C:/ruby/23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1569:in `fu_each_src_dest'
        from C:/ruby/23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:517:in `mv'
        from (irb):5
        from C:/ruby/23-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
```

Is this a known limitation? Or a bug? Or am I just doing something wrong? Googling yields `chmod` results for Linux systems, but I don't think that's relevant for Windows (running script as administrator regardless).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the issue was the `file = File.new(File.join("first_directory", "test_file"))`. This actually opens the file, which blocks the rename operation (which is how the move is performed) as the file is currently "in use". Removing this line and using the file path instead of the object in `FileUtils.move` works as expected.

This can similarly be observed by creating the file object, then trying to rename the file in the explorer: `The action can't be completed because the file is open in ruby.exe...`

Comment: I had a very similar issue, the file was opened via `Tempfile.open` and I had to use `.close` on that to make sure the file is rename- and move-able. Thanks for the hint!